Error: Missing argument 'CLUSTER_CONFIG_FILE'. Ray GCP
I have created a GCP Ray cluster from the ray cluster dashboard within GCP, I have also created a Ray cluster locally via docker compose.
Is there an easy way to generate the ray cluster config?
For example here is the base Dockerfile I used on the ray head and nodes:
FROM python:3.11.9-slim
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install libgl1 tesseract-ocr git -y \
    && apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev -y \
    && apt-get install poppler-utils -y \
    && apt-get install libmagic1 -y \
    && apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev build-essential g++ curl -y \
    && apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all -y \
    && apt-get install libpq-dev -y
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | bash -s -- -y
RUN echo '. /root/.cargo/env' >> /root/.bashrc
ENV PATH=$PATH:/root/.cargo/bin/
RUN echo PATH: $PATH
RUN ls /root/.cargo/env
ENV PYO3_USE_ABI3_FORWARD_COMPATIBILITY=1

WORKDIR /app
COPY vertexai_loaders/pyproject.toml /app
COPY vertexai_loaders/requirements.txt /app
COPY vertexai_loaders/poetry.lock /app
COPY vertexai_loaders/README.md /app
COPY vertexai_loaders/src/ /app/src
COPY vertexai_loaders/alembic/ /app/alembic
COPY vertexai_loaders/alembic.ini /app/alembic.ini
COPY secrets /secrets
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install psycopg2
RUN pip install -e .
RUN pip install "ray[default]"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN echo done

EXPOSE 6479
EXPOSE 8265
EXPOSE 10001

And the snippet for the ray cluster in the docker-compose.yaml
  ray-head:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile.ray.cluster
    ports:
      - 6479:6479  # default (6379) but that is also the default for redis port for starting jobs on head node
      - 8265:8265  # default ray dashboard port
      - 10001:10001  # ray client server port
    volumes:
      - ray-data:/var/lib/ray/data
    command: sh -c 'ray start --head --dashboard-host=0.0.0.0 --dashboard-port=8265 --port=6479 --ray-client-server-port=10001 --block'
    networks:
      - net

  ray-worker-1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile.ray.cluster
    depends_on:
      - ray-head
    command: ray start --address=ray-head:6479 --ray-client-server-port=10001 --block
    environment:
      - RAY_HEAD_IP=ray-head
    networks:
      - net
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

  ray-worker-2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile.ray.cluster
    depends_on:
      - ray-head
    command: ray start --address=ray-head:6479 --ray-client-server-port=10001 --block
    environment:
      - RAY_HEAD_IP=ray-head
    networks:
      - net
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

  ray-worker-3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfile.ray.cluster
    depends_on:
      - ray-head
    command: ray start --address=ray-head:6479 --ray-client-server-port=10001 --block
    environment:
      - RAY_HEAD_IP=ray-head
    networks:
      - net
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

volumes:
  ray-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
  ui-network:
    external: false

ray config yaml minimal:
auth:
  ssh_user: ubuntu
cluster_name: minimal
provider:
  availability_zone: us-west1-a
  project_id: genai-qa-1234
  region: us-west1
  type: gcp

And the traceback error:


(venv_311) 15:08:59 jm@jm:~/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders:
jm/add-ray-raven-tf:$ ray up ./ray-deploy-gcp.yaml
Cluster: minimal

2024-07-08 15:09:25,152 INFO util.py:382 -- setting max workers for head node type to 0
2024-07-08 15:09:25,152 INFO util.py:386 -- setting max workers for ray_worker_small to 2
Checking GCP environment settings
2024-07-08 15:09:28,845 INFO config.py:579 -- _configure_key_pair: Private key not specified in config, using/home/jm/.ssh/ray-autoscaler_gcp_us-west1_genai-qa-1234_ubuntu_0.pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/bin/ray", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/scripts/scripts.py", line 2615, in main
    return cli()
           ^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/cli_logger.py", line 856, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/scripts/scripts.py", line 1321, in up
    create_or_update_cluster(
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/commands.py", line 314, in create_or_update_cluster
    config = _bootstrap_config(config, no_config_cache=no_config_cache)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/commands.py", line 416, in _bootstrap_config
    resolved_config = provider_cls.bootstrap_config(config)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/gcp/node_provider.py", line 277, in bootstrap_config
    return bootstrap_gcp(cluster_config)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/gcp/config.py", line 393, in bootstrap_gcp
    config = _configure_subnet(config, compute)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/gcp/config.py", line 608, in _configure_subnet
    subnets = _list_subnets(config, compute)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/jm/repos/testray/vertexai_loaders/venv_311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/gcp/config.py", line 654, in _list_subnets
    return response["items"]
           ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'items'

I also tried to use the in browser GCP SSH, and dug around the ray --help but didn't find an easy way to generate the ray config yaml?
How can I do that?
Of course I had a look at: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/vms/references/ray-cluster-configuration.html#cluster-config
However, even looking at each config key, its not clear, and seems prone to mistakes especially considering each value would need to be hand crafted and tried. Seems pretty weird considering its an already deployed cluster.
I also tried find / | grep '.yml\|.yaml | less and didn't see anywhere on the head node a pre-existing configuration file.
Related:

https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/ray-core/handling-dependencies.html

